# Как получить строку или число из фильтра в хэндлер в aiogram 3

Tags: python, aiogram

Мне нужно получить из фильтра не булевое значение, а строку и передать её в хэндлер. 
Как я могу этого добится?

вот часть кода:

```
dp.message.register(give_me_code_pt, IsIHAveThisPtCode(), languages.PYTHON_HAVE_BEEN_GOT)
```

`give_me_code_pt` -  это хэндлер в который нужно получить строку;
`IsIHAveThisPtCode()` -  это фильтр который должен возвращать строку;\ `languages.PYTHON_HAVE_BEEN_GOT` -  это состояние из которого вызывается хэндлер.

Я ничего не пробовал. Я не представляю как получить строку, которую вернёт фильтр в хендлере